# Creating GeoTiff from Tiff+WorldFile+Proj

Tags: open-source-gis, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I'm currently using the global mapper export function to convert my tiffs+worldfile+projection file to geotiff.  Is there a commandline tool (for Linux) that lets me do the same thing?
"gdaltranslate" doesn't seem to use the projection file.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the "-a_srs filename.prj" parameter with gdal_translate to accomplish this.  From the [documentation](http://gdal.org/gdal_translate.html):

> The srs_def may be any of the usual
>   GDAL/OGR forms, complete WKT, PROJ.4,
>   EPSG:n **or a file containing the WKT**.

(emphasis added)

Answer (score 2):

Use geotifcp (listgeo for the opposite job)

More on http://trac.osgeo.org/geotiff/

Available in ubuntu/debian with

```
sudo apt-get install geotiff-bin libgeotiff-epsg
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI if you run GlobalMapper with Wine under Linux it seems most of the functions are working, although it is not supported. I have also used GlobalMapper with Wine under Linux with some luck (although some menus and options crashes). More information here: http://www.globalmapperforum.com/forums/technical-support/4088-linux.html